# How to get config.xml for jenkins pipeline job

Tags: docker, security, jenkins, config, multibranch-pipeline

I have a requirment, need to backup config.xml for my jenkins jobs. Here i have created lot of pipeline jobs and build them using docker slave. Please help how to get config.xml for those pipeline job to backup purposes?

Comment: There is probably a way to do this, but may I ask why you don't generate your jenkins jobs through code? That way you don't need those backups! To generate jobs through code you simply need the amazing job-dsl plugin => https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin

Answer (score 1):

It is in your Jenkins installation folder: jobs -> "Your Job's Name" -> config.xml

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the file is to append **config.xml** at the end of the job url, e.g.

```
Job URL:   http://YOUR_JENKINS/job/YOUR_DEPLOY/
Conig URL: http://YOUR_JENKINS/job/YOUR_DEPLOY/config.xml
```